# Troubleshooting client-side JS problems with a Drupal site?

Tags: javascript, debugging, drupal, civicrm

I administrate a Drupal 7.14 based CiviCRM (4.1.3) install and am trying to troubleshoot an elusive issue with the UI. Several (but not all) Javascript based elements of the site have stopped working, i.e. clicking on a dropdown arrow to display "advanced options" or trying to open a calendar widget. Here is what I've tried:
- I checked directory permissions
- I deleted JS cache (~/public_html/civicrm/sites/default/files/js) and other page cache (~/public_html/civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c).
- I updated Drupal modules to latest releases (haven't updated to Drupal 7.15, but this issue didn't coincide with Drupal 7.14 update, so I'm assuming this isn't the issue)
- I enabled (then cleared cache) and disabled (then cleared cache) then re-enabled JS and CSS caching/compression/aggregation in drupal

Does anyone have suggestions as to where I should begin in troubleshooting this in a more granular way? I'm a total novice to js debugging, so any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: you can start by telling us what is the problem

Comment: What browser(s) are you using to test this? There are different tools for firefox, chrome, safari, and even ie that you can use to troubleshoot this sort of thing.

Comment: Ibu: sorry if this wasn't clear - the problem is listed in my second sentence above, namely some Javascript elements have stopped functioning.

Comment: Erin: I've been using Firefox w/ firebug, but haven't had much luck beyond that. I'm perfectly happy to try with Chrome or Safari if you've got any tips I can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Civicrm this usually means that your resource URLs are incorrect. Please take a look at step 14 in the wiki page I link to below. Even if you have not moved your site your host may have changed some paths so if step 14 doesn't work alone then check all the steps in this wiki page:

[Moving an Existing Installation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC41/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location)